# How to get row data using row id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

```
var $grid = $("#grid"),  
var dataFromTheRow = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);
```

Tried this but no luck.

Comment: What is `#list`? Shouldn't that be `#grid`?

Comment: That was typo.var dataFromTheRow = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);

Comment: Why don't you use the variable that you just set? `$grid.jqGrid(...)`

Comment: The code should work as long as `rowId` is a valid row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented before rowId should be valid - i.e row with this id should exists. If you do not know the id of the rows you can use the method [getDataIDs](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#method-list) to see all the available id of the rows

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var dataFromTheRow = jQuery('#grid').getRowData(rowId);
```